# What is the meaning of the overlapping region on OTP-perfect secrecy diagram?

Tags: entropy, perfect-secrecy

I'm new to cryptography. I want to ask about OTP-perfect secrecy diagram like figure below:

> [image]

On the overlapping region (middle), notated by R(X;Y;Z). R can be calculated by I(X;Y) - I(X;Y|Z). That region is symmetric in X, Y, Z and can be negative. For example when X and Y are independent bits, and Z = X xor Y, then I(X;Y) = I(X;Z) = I(Y;Z) = 0, but I(X;Y|Z) > 0.

What is the "meaning/philosophy" of that region? I mean when the region is negative, when the region is positive, and how to describe that?

I have been trying to find the answer but no result.

Comment: Could you define what $H$, $I$, and $R$ mean?

Comment: I'm assuming H is entropy (or conditional entropy), I is mutual information (or conditional mutual information), R, not sure. Where did this image come from? A reverse image search turned up nothing.

Comment: Give us some reference to help u better

Comment: all : sorry for late reply, i just returned from a trip. Thanks for your response ---

@mephisto : H entropy, I mutual information, R I still do know, but according to Chris's answer bellow, R is multivariate mutual information (???) ---

mikeazo & sashank : I picked up the pic from lecture note in computer science, unconditional security in cryptography by stefan wolf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your diagram is a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) that illustrates the information measures between the correlated random variables $X,Y$ and $Z$.

- $H(X)$ refers to a complete circle and is the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_entropy) of $X$,
- $H(X|YZ)$ is the entropy of $X$ under the observation of $Y$ and $Z$,
- $I(X;Y|Z)$ is the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) between $X$ and $Y$ under the observation Z,
- $R(X;Y;Z)$ seems to represent $I(X;Y;Z)$, the mutual information between X,Y and Z.

The region $R(X;Y;Z)$ is thus the amount of information that is shared by the random variables $X,Y$ and $Z$. If the random variables are completely independent, then this region is empty.

I don't know exactly how this is related to OTP. I guess that you typically want maximal entropy for OTP, and you don't want to have any mutual information between the variables.

PS: After writing most of this answer I found a wikipedia page about [multivariate mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information), which seems to correspond exactly to this question.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris.. I think i found the answer from you.. I will read it first..